# What is the equivalent of SQL's IN keyword in R?

Tags: sql, r, language-comparisons

In SQL, you can easily avoid multiple OR conditions if you're looking for many values of a particular variable (column) by using IN.
For example :

```
SELECT * FROM colors WHERE color in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')
```

How would I do that in R?
I am currently having to do it like this:

```
shortlisted_colors <- subset(colors, color == 'Red' | color == 'Blue' | color == 'Green')
```

What is a better way?

Comment: Use the function `%in%`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
shortlisted_colors <- subset(colors, color %in% c('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'))
```

Comment: When I do a summary(shortlisted_colors), It still shows me observations for other colors but shows their counts as 0.

Comment: How do I remove the rows that have the other colors?

Comment: It sounds like `color` is a `factor` variable and not a `character` variable. If `colors` is your `data.frame`, you can do `colors$color <- as.character(colors$color)` and this should clear up the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What is as.character doing here? Any good documentation on this will help too.

Comment: Sure no problem, it just changed the class of your column `color` from `factor` to `character`. Type `?as.character` and `?as.factor` in your console and read the help file; they are two different object classes in R. Although they might look the same on the surface, they have different properties.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it might be difficult to search on "in" but the answer is "%in%". Searching also might be difficult because `in` is a reserved word in R because of its use in the iterator specification in `for`-loops:

```
subset(colors, color %in% c('Red' ,'Blue','Green') )
```

See:

```
?match
?'%in%'   # since you need to quote names with special symbols in them
```

The use of "%"-signs to enclose user-defined infix function names is illustrated on that page, but you will then get a leg up on understanding how @hadley has raised that approach to a much higher level in his `dplyr`-package. If you have a solid background in SQL then looping back to see what dplyr offers should be very satisfying. I understand that `dplyr`-functions are really a front-end to SQL operations in many instances.